# TextExpander for Android

Tags: automation, text-input

I'm on a Mac and iPhone. Going to switch to Android and Windows.

[TextExpander](http://smilesoftware.com/TextExpander/index.html) is an app that is "expanding custom keyboard shortcuts into frequently-used text". In other words: a *text expansion* tool.

For example, when I type `gm1`, my email shows up. When I hit `d2`, I see today's date, "130830".

I currently have TextExpander on the Mac, have the library in Dropbox, and sync it to iPhone so that I have all my snippets on both Mac and iPhone (well, at least in the iPhone apps I write in like plain text).

I know that

- AHK kan do snippets via `:*:gm::[my email address]`
- [Breevy](http://www.16software.com/breevy/) is a text expander for Windows

But can I make text expansion play as nice on Android-Windows as on iPhone-Mac?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check [Textspansion](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.designatum_1393.textspansion) that works for Android.

I'm not affiliated with the author although we make a text expansion software for Windows.

Comment: TextExpansion does not come close to TextExpander.

1. It does not sync with any computer app.
2. Expansion does not make [shortcut] into [expanded thing] when I **type it**, instead, I need to: exit my current app, go to the Expansion app, find the entry I want, tap the entry I want, then paste.

Answer (score 0):

> But can I make text expansion play as nice on android-windows as on iPhone-mac?

[Blueduino](http://www.blueduino.com) has a soft keyboard mode that allows to type text which is then expanded, it's seamless integration.

It also shows a small icon and proposals if a shortcut is detected which works well with most of the apps. Using it as an accessibility service is the main operational mode for modern devices which allows to use it with the devices' stock keyboard or the keyboard of your choices.

What's cool is the support of shortcuts when used with Bluetooth hardware keyboards which is what you want e.g. with Android Desktop.

It doesn't offer sync with text on your computer, but shortcuts can be exported to a file and then imported again.

It's in the [Google Play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.weebmeister.textexpander.macro).

Comment: How do you like it, do you have pros or cons?
Any enhancement ideas?

Comment: Snce you're asking for enhancement ideas, I assume you're affiliated with the app. Note that [Stack Exchange expects users to disclose their affiliation clearly on the post](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/promotion). Otherwise, it might be deemed as spamming/astroturfing. Thanks